# Why does a newline character count as two keys in a BTreeMap?

Tags: char, rust, newline

I'm creating a compression/decompression library in Rust using Huffman encoding. One of the first steps is creating a data structure that contains all unique characters and the number of occurrences. I'm starting with just a simple text file, and having issues related to newline 'characters'.

My first attempt at solving this problem was constructing a `BTreeMap`, essentially a key-value pair of unique characters and their occurrences, respectively. Unfortunately, a newline 'character' is \n, which I think is not being handled corrected due to being two characters. I then converted the `BTreeMap` into a `Vec` to order by value, but that didn't solve the newline issue.

Here's my initial attempt at my `comp` binary package. Calling the binary is done using `cargo`, and my sample file is reproduced at the end of this question:

```
cargo run <text-file-in> <compressed-output-file>
```

**main.rs**

```
extern crate comp;

use std::env;
use std::process;
use std::io::prelude::*;

use comp::Config;

fn main() {
    // Collect command-line args into a vector of strings
    let mut stderr = std::io::stderr();

    let config = Config::new(env::args()).unwrap_or_else(|err| {
        writeln!(&mut stderr, "Parsing error: {}", err).expect("Could not write to stderr");
        process::exit(1)
    });

    println!("Filename In: {}", config.filename_in);
    println!("Filename Out: {}", config.filename_out);

    if let Err(e) = comp::run(config) {
        writeln!(&mut stderr, "Application error: {}", e).expect("Could not write to stderr");
        process::exit(1);
    }
}
```

**lib.rs**

```
use std::collections::btree_map::BTreeMap;
use std::error::Error;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::iter::FromIterator;

pub struct Config {
    pub filename_in: String,
    pub filename_out: String
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new(mut args: std::env::Args) -> Result<Config, &'static str> {
        args.next();

        let filename_in = match args.next() {
            Some(arg) => arg,
            None => return Err("Didn't get a filename_in string"),
        };

        let filename_out = match args.next() {
            Some(arg) => arg,
            None => return Err("Didn't get a filename_out string"),
        };

        Ok(Config {
            filename_in: filename_in,
            filename_out: filename_out,
        })
    }
}

pub fn run(config: Config) -> Result<(), Box<Error>> {
    let mut f = File::open(config.filename_in)?;

    let mut contents = String::new();
    f.read_to_string(&mut contents)?;

    for line in contents.lines() {
        println!("{}", line);
    }

    // Put unique occurrences into a BTreeMap
    let mut count = BTreeMap::new();

    for c in contents.chars() {
        *count.entry(c).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }

    // Put contents into a Vec to order by value
    let mut v = Vec::from_iter(count);
    v.sort_by(|&(_, a), &(_, b)| b.cmp(&a));

    // Print key-value pair of input file
    println!("Number of occurrences of each character");
    for &(key, value) in v.iter() {
        println!("{}: {}", key, value);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Sample text file, **poem.txt**:

```
I'm nobody! Who are you?
Are you nobody, too?
Then there's a pair of us — don't tell!
They'd banish us, you know.

How dreary to be somebody!
How public, like a frog
To tell your name the livelong day
To an admiring bog!
```

Usage:

```
$ cargo run poem.txt poem
   Compiling comp v0.1.0 (file:///home/chris/Projects/learn_rust/comp-rs)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 1.96 secs
     Running `target/debug/comp poem.txt poem`
Filename In: poem.txt
Filename Out: poem
I'm nobody! Who are you?
Are you nobody, too?
Then there's a pair of us — don't tell!
They'd banish us, you know.

How dreary to be somebody!
How public, like a frog
To tell your name the livelong day
To an admiring bog!
Number of occurrences of each character
 : 36
o: 24
e: 15
a: 10
n: 10
y: 10
        < What's going on here?
: 9     < What's going on here?
r: 9
d: 8
l: 8
b: 7
i: 7
t: 7
u: 7
h: 6
s: 5
!: 4
': 4
T: 4
g: 4
m: 4
,: 3
w: 3
?: 2
H: 2
f: 2
k: 2
p: 2
.: 1
A: 1
I: 1
W: 1
c: 1
v: 1
—: 1
```

Comment: *a newline 'character' is [...] two characters* — no, it's not.

Comment: I added current output, which shows the problem. I'd be happy to repost it to code review if necessary

Comment: You main problem with this is that there **is no question**. You haven't said "why is this broken" or anything vaguely like it. Stack Overflow is a **question and answer** site, but there's no obvious question.

Comment: How should I rephrase the question? I think I need to newline character to be a key in my key-value pair, but it's currently two keys.

Comment: "What's going on here?"  You're displaying a newline character.  Which is starting a new line.  What did you *expect* to happen?

Comment: Or put it this way: What does `println!("{}: {}", '\n', 9);` do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Unfortunately, a newline 'character' is `\n`, which I think is not being handled corrected due to being two characters.

No, it is not. A newline character (UTF-8 codepoint 0x0A) is a single character.

> I think I need to newline character to be a key in my key-value pair, but it's currently two keys.

No, it is not. Such a thing cannot happen "accidentally" either. If  we somehow had two keys, you would have to call `insert` twice; there's no built-in concept of a multi-key map.

All that's happening here is that a newline character is *printed* as... a newline!

```
y: 10

: 9
```

If you take the time to create a [MCVE](/help/mcve), you'd see this quickly:

```
fn main() {
    let c = '\n';
    println!(">{}<", c);
    println!(">{:?}<", c);
}
```

```
>
<
>'\n'<
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses and answer @Shepmaster, you're totally right. I didn't know where the issue was - I thought it was related to BTreeMap. I should have taken more time to break it down into a MCVE and use debug output instead of normal output. I'll delete the code review post and consider this an answer. Thanks for your help patience.

Answer (score 2):

The newline character is actually an *escape sequence* character.  This means that if you write it as `\n` in the code which shows up as two characters, it's actually a placeholder for a single character - a new line - and should be treated as 'one character' in the program during runtime.

The core issue you have here is that you're using `println` to print it out to the command line and actually ***printing*** an new line, as the `\n` is interpreted to mean "A new line".  This is why, when you use `println` here, you get the behavior you see.  This is typical of ***most*** languages.

While this adds a little additional bit of code, you may wish to do something like this instead to specially-handle new-line data being printed:

```
// Print key-value pair of input file
println!("Number of occurrences of each character");
for &(key, value) in v.iter() {
    if key == '\n' {
        println!("\\n": {}, value);
    } else {
        println!("{}: {}", key, value);
    }
}
```

Consider as explained by Shepmaster though to create an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to thoroughly test things, it helps rule out misinterpretation of what is actually happening behind the scenes.

(NOTE: I am not a Rust master; there is probably a better way to achieve the above, but this is the shortest solution I came up with in a short period of time)